# Reuse entry form layout in custom module

Tags: control-panel, entry, modules

I'm currently developing a custom module.
I created a section called "bookings" with an entry type containing some fields.
I designed the form layout as i wanted.
In the CP, the Entry section allows me to create / edit / delete this section.

Now, i'd like to be able to reuse the booking form layout in my custom module.
Is it possible ?

Thx

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think i was going the wrong path.
Entries are not the proper element to choose.
I need to go with custom element types : https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/element-types.html